# How do I properly bind ObservableCollection to listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I am trying to bind a collection of ViewModels to a listview but for some reason it is not working.
This is the ListView:

```
ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BankList}"> 
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Bank Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BankName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Bank Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BankAddress}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And this is the ViewModel containing the ObservableCollection.
GetBanks() is just a method used to populate the collection.

It's like the BankList property is binded at all in the XAML, but I checked with some breakpoints and the DataContext(BankListViewModel) of the BankListView is set correctly so the BankList should be recognized

```
public class BankListViewModel : VMBase, IBankListViewModel
   {
    public ObservableCollection<BankViewModel> BankList
    {
        get { return GetBanks(); }
        set
        {
            bankList = value;
            //this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<BankEvent>().Subscribe(i => this.bankList.Add(new BankViewModel(i, eventAggregator)));
            OnPropertyChanged("BankList");
        }
    public BankListViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.BankList = GetBanks();

        foreach(var item in this.BankList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.BankName);
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you check Output window ? If there are binding errors, WPF outputs them there...

Comment: use Snoop and you can see details of the binding etc at runtime

Comment: No binding errors in the OutputWindow, gonna check with Snoop.

Comment: well I just used your code and it works fine ..

Comment: whats inside get banks ?

Comment: GetBanks() grabs some values from a database and adds them to the list. I found the problem in the end, the bindings were alright, the problem was with the DataContext;

Comment: works for me as well making some assumptions on whats in GetBanks...  Are you sure GetBanks is doing what you want it to do maybe debug by manually inserting into the ObservableCollection in GetBanks as maybe the code to load from the db is not returning anything.

Comment: In the end the problem was a mistyped letter when assigning the DataContext.